# Apache fails to Redirect

Tags: apache, redirect

I'm running Apache 2.4.6 on Oracle Linux 7.4

I have a redirect that, well, fails to redirect.

Here's an excerpt from my httpd.con file, showing the relevant VirtualHost definitions.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin mbobak@obscured.com
     ServerName obscured.obscured.com
     Redirect permanent / https://obscured.obscured.com/ords/f?p=300:
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerAdmin mbobak@obscured.com
     ServerName obscured.obscured.com
     Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;"
     JkMount /* domain4
     SSLEngine On
     SSLProxyEngine On
     SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
     SSLHonorCipherOrder on
     SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4"
     SSLCertificateFile      /etc/httpd/conf/ssl_certs/obscured.com/a622fe544d2b98f7.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/httpd/conf/ssl_certs/obscured.com/obscured.key
     SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl_certs/obscured.com/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

I have no idea what is wrong.  Instead of redirecting to `https://obscured.obscured.com/ords/f?p=300:`, I end up at `https://obscured.obscured.com`

Help?

Comment: I don't think you can use mod_alias with a query string.  Have you tried mod_rewrite?

Comment: Hi Mike,  sorry, I'm very much a newbie....could you provide a bit more info?  I have tried various mod_rewrite RewriteRule stuff, but with no success.

Comment: Could you try (1) removing everything from ? onwards (2) removing the trailing :

Comment: Just to rule it out did you try, http://obscured.obscured.com/

Comment: What does the network traffic say it's doing? Check with your browser's developer tools. Maybe your browser cached the redirect. And you did reload/restart the server, right? And check the server logs?

Answer (score 1):

If possible you could use your .htaccess file, set it to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} obscured.obscured.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://obscured.obscured.com/ords/f?p=300: [R=301,NC]
```

Make sure to add a blank .htaccess file in your ords sub-directory so that the redirect does't occur there.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to run a wget to find out what really happened:

```
wget --server-response http://obscured.obscured.com
```